# jsoup to w3c-document: INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR

Tags: java, dom, jsoup

My usecase: Get html-pages by jsoup and returns a w3c-DOM for further processing by XML-transformations:

```
...
org.jsoup.nodes.Document document = connection.get();
org.w3c.dom.Document dom = new W3CDom().fromJsoup(document);
...
```

Works well for most documents but for some it throws INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR without telling where.

It seems extremely difficult to find the error. I changed the code to first import the url to a String and then checking for bad characters by regexp. But that does not help for bad attributes (eg. without value) etc.

My current solution is to minimize the risk by removing elements by tag in the jsoup-document (head, img, script ...).

Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: Don't forget to mark your chosen answer as accepted for closing this question.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `outputSettings` to 'XML' for your document:

```
document
  .outputSettings()
  .syntax(OutputSettings.Syntax.xml);

document 
    .outputSettings()
    .charset("UTF-8");
```

This should ensure that the resulting XML is valid.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately this cannot clean badly formatted html against wich browser are quite tolerant. eg: 
<meta name="description" content="US-Autorin Alexandra Kleeman nimmt in ihrem Debüt-Roman " a="" wie="" b="" und="" c"="" unseren="" perfektionismus="" auseinander="" –="" indem="" sie="" sich="" selbst="" reflektiert."="" />. Probably originates from bad configuration/use of cms. out of my control.

Comment: @Jürg M hmm, that's a pretty bad formatting. Take a look at Jsoup's `Cleaner` (http://jsoup.org/cookbook/cleaning-html/whitelist-sanitizer) maybe it can help - at least in removing elements. An other option would be to add something like `HtmlCleaner` (http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/) to your proccessing pipeline. It should be able to output well-formatted XML.

Comment: Thank you very much; this solved the problem: Whitelist whiteList = Whitelist.relaxed(); Cleaner cleaner = new Cleaner(whiteList); jsoupDom = cleaner.clean(jsoupDom); "relaxed" in deed means relaxed developer...

Answer (score 1):

Solution found by OP in reply to [nyname00](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5935221/nyname00):

> Thank you very much; this solved the problem:
>
> ```
> Whitelist whiteList = Whitelist.relaxed();
> Cleaner cleaner = new Cleaner(whiteList);
> jsoupDom = cleaner.clean(jsoupDom);
> ```
>
> "relaxed" in deed means relaxed developer...